# Multiple headers in Rest Assured does not work and respond with a 401 Unauthorized code

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Need to know if I am making some mistake in passing the headers in the below code (Is this the right way of passing multiple headers in rest assured?)  I get an exception as followed in Rest Assured . The header values passed works well in Jmeter and postman.

**Exception:**

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <401>.

**Code:**

```
    import org.junit.Test;
    import com.jayway.restassured.*;
    import com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
    import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;

    public class APIresponse

    {

    @Test
        public void response ()
        {
            given().
                header("Id", "abc"). 
                header("Key", "NuDVhdsfYmNkDLOZQ").
                header("ConId", "xyz").
            when().
                get("testme/api/uk?Id=DT44FR100731").
            then().
                //contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                body("response.code", equalTo("200"));
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you sure "Id","Key" and "ConId" are headers for rest service. For me it seems like parameters of REST api. Also is it a GET service?

Answer (score 0):

401 - Unauthorized status will result when you don't pass authentication info to REST service.

You can pass authentication as follows:

```
given().
   auth().
   basic("userid","password").
   header().
   ....
expect().
   statusCode(200)
   log().ifError()
...
```

You can find more authentication schemes supported by REST-assured in this given [github link](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/com/jayway/restassured/itest/java/AuthenticationITest.java)

Comment: No authentication required for our API...           Its only headers where the Id and keys are passed...

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <401>.

 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)

Answer (score 0):

Below code will be worked with **io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.2.1**

```
    public void response ()
        {
           Header idHeader = new Header("Id", "abc");
           Header keyHeader = new Header("Key", "NuDVhdsfYmNkDLOZQ");
           Header conIdHeader = new Header("ConId", "xyz");
           Headers headers = new Headers(idHeader, keyHeader, conIdHeader);
            given().
                headers(headers).                   
            when().
                get("testme/api/uk?Id=DT44FR100731").
            then().
                //contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                body("response.code", equalTo("200"));
        }
```